# Tagging an Android Release

Tags: android, git, tags, android-source

I currently have my own mirror of the AOSP project. I can manually branch a few repositories, but I'm not sure how to tag all repositories in my mirror to save a release. Is it a special "repo" command to tag everything?

Answer (score 4):

There is no tag command with `repo` to my knowledge, but you can use `repo forall` command:

Something like:

```
repo forall -c 'git tag TAGNAME'
```

should work.

https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html#forall

Comment: Prefer `git tag -a TAGNAME` to create an annotated tag, in which case you probably also want to set the tag comment via `-m` or `-F` to avoid getting hundreds of tag message prompts.

Comment: Do I push the tags to Gerrit somehow? Will "repo upload" push my tags to my mirror?

Comment: @ross.squires you can use `repo forall` also to push the tags but I think Android Gerrit ACL will allow only users from specific groups to push tags.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you probably *do* want to tag every git and the answer by @ouah explains how, but see my comment about creating annotated tags. Keep in mind that while a tag tells you which commit in that git was part of the release, you still have no idea which gits contain the tag. To sync a complete workspace for a release you'll have to check all possible gits if they contain the tag in question (`git ls-remote` should be helpful), and craft a manifest based on that information. Alternatively, create a commit in the manifest git and list all gits there (and tag that commit too).

Now, if you intend to create thousands of tags (e.g. because you have a frequently running CI job that builds everything and you want to record the state of each build) you should consider that Git is somewhat inefficient with that amount of references. It may be wiser to instead create a static manifest (`repo manifest -r -o manifest.xml`) containing the checked out commit of each git.

The downside is that you can't say e.g. `git diff your-release-1.0..HEAD` but have to fetch the static manifest and pick up the SHA-1 to compare against from there (a task that's easily automated, obviously). The upside is that you can easily sync a full workspace, especially if you store the static manifest files in the manifest git. For example, if you store them in the master branch (regardless of what manifest branch they were built from), `repo init -u ... -m your-release-1.0.xml` could be used to prepare your workspace.